# How to use base viewcontroller for other view controllers？

Tags: ios, view, radix

There are many views that look the same,a toolbar on the top of the view,and some items on it.So I wonder if I can set a base view controller and other view controllers inherit
from it.Because I don't want to set these items ever time I create a view controller,are there any good ideas?Is it possible to create a base view controller?

Comment: Yes, thats one of the reason we have inheritance in OOP right?

Comment: You are right,but I just don't know where I can put my codes.I just want to add a toolbar,should I add it in viewDidLoad or initWithNib...?

Comment: You could put in both i guess, but typically if you are subclassing initWithNib would be a better place (although the inherent meaning of the method would change). But I'm entirely sure what we are talking about here. If you could add more details in the question to what you are trying to do maybe i (or someone else) could help.

Comment: For a performance reason you should'n touch your `self.view` before `viewDidLoad`. So, `viewDidLoad` is the best place for creating your custom views and adding it into subviews.

Comment: OK,I get it ,thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually I add codes in initWithNib...,it works right,but I think viewDidLoad is a better place!

Comment: Yeah, read [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html) to achieve better performance in you app

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 5.0+ you can use:

```
- (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController
```

Comment: I want to support iOS 4.x,so this method is not good for me!But thanks anyway!